# Возможно ли в MatLAB визуализировать траекторию и анимацию движения робота-манипулятора при известных координатах?

Tags: matlab

Известны путевые точки по которым должна проходить траектория движения робота-манипулятора. Возможно ли в MatLAB  визуализировать эту траекторию и анимацию движения робота?

```
p1=A1 -33.8969193, A2 -78.9970322, A3 98.2957916, A4 304.597107, A5 18.9458447, A6 -56.7847748, E1 -7.09412794E-15, E2 41895.7656 

p2=X 1214.55933, Y 1427.87708, Z 776.315063, A -2.21756506, B 40.4588852, C -92.9536591, E1 -7.09412794E-15, E2 5035.86230

p3=X 1210.57593, Y 1429.51245, Z 604.782410, A -2.24066806, B 40.9752350, C -92.9837952, E1 -7.09412794E-15, E2 5035.86230

p4=X 1216.69104, Y 1429.17371, Z 594.248169, A -2.68645883, B 50.9661140, C -93.6014633, E1 8.56784290E-23, E2 5035.86230 

p5=X 1222.99170, Y 1429.13208, Z 582.369141, A -4.01838255, B 65.0880203, C -95.1596451, E1 -7.09412794E-15, E2 5035.86230 

p6=X 1225.72498, Y 1428.44519, Z 571.774353, A -6.12927, B 73.9510574, C -97.4061890, E1 -7.09412794E-15, E2 5035.86230 

p7=X 1227.22485, Y 1429.49780, Z 554.312439, A -29.2634926, B 86.5380630, C -120.732971, E1 -7.09412794E-15, E2 5035.86230
```

Только начала изучать MatLAB. Во всех найденных примерах траектория и точки сами генерируются, что в моем случае не подходит.